# Can I not vote to re-close a question that I originally VTCed that was since reopened?

Tags: discussion

Viz [the meta-q about can I call certain humans mongrels in a work of fantasy](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11344/puzzled-is-calling-a-mixed-race-person-a-mongrel-really-a-matter-of-opinion), I close-voted the [actual ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/440343/can-mongrel-be-used-to-refer-to-people) and since then it was re-opened and I would like to closevote it again, but I don't think the system is letting me.

So, can a user not vote anew to close a question that was closed but has been reopened?

Edit: And if not, why not?

Comment: related: [How do I change the subcategory of a flag?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10183/how-do-i-change-the-subcategory-of-a-flag/10185#10185)

Comment: This sound like a case of vote-closing addiction.

Answer (score 9):

No. You can only vote to close a question once.

Your opinion is known and you have expressed it. Five other people have had a contrary view; you cannot have another bite of the cherry and vote again.

This has been the case since [at least 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99234/184638), when Jeff Attwood explained

> You are only allowed to cast one close or reopen vote on any given post, largely to prevent close/reopen wars involving the same cast of characters.

Comment: But you are allowed to cast VTC  a second time if the first time was unsuccessful. IOW I vote to close a question but that question doesn't receive the 5 votes necessary for closure when my vote has expired I can recast it. Correct?

Comment: @Andrew is this the case even when the question has been (substantially) edited?

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting

Comment: I might add that I am quite certain that if a question devolved into a political advocacy of hateful morals too fast for moderation it could be flagged as offensive and reviewed at a higher level of SE .  I think there were fair arguments about it crossing the line into "writing advice" but I did not see anything close to advocating the propriety of  calling humans words that meant they were less than human. People are called 'pigs' and and "snakes". Calling a police officer a "pig" is highly offensive, but was common.  Would a 60's hippy use the word "pig" is language, not writing IMO